How do I import multiple .csv files with the same columns that are stored in my Databricks workspace and store them in a single table
I have 90 .csv files containing data and they all have the same columns. I would like read all the csv files and store them in a single table. The .csv files are all stored in a map called 'Data' in my workspace. When I keep getting the error that the path cannot be found.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CombineCSVFiles").getOrCreate()

# Specify the path where the CSV files are stored in the workspace
workspace_path = "My workspace path"

# List of CSV files in the workspace directory
# Use dbutils.fs.ls for workspace paths if necessary
file_list = [file.path for file in dbutils.fs.ls(workspace_path) if file.path.endswith(".csv")]

# Initialize an empty list to hold DataFrames
df_list = []

# Read each CSV file into a DataFrame and add to the list
for file in file_list:
    df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(file)
    df_list.append(df)

# Combine all DataFrames into a single DataFrame
combined_df = df_list[0]
for df in df_list[1:]:
    combined_df = combined_df.union(df)

# Convert the datetime column to Timestamp type if necessary
combined_df = combined_df.withColumn("datetime", col("datetime").cast("timestamp"))

# Sort the combined DataFrame by the datetime column
sorted_df = combined_df.orderBy(col("datetime"))

# Show the result (or you can save it to a table or file)
sorted_df.show()

# Optionally, save the combined DataFrame as a new table
sorted_df.write.format("delta").saveAsTable("combined_sorted_table")


What is the complete text of the error message, and where are the files stored that you want to process?

The error occurs for the following line:
file_list = [file.path for file in dbutils.fs.ls(workspace_path) if file.path.endswith(".csv")]
And goes as follows:
ExecutionError: An error occurred while calling o397.ls.
: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory /Workspace/Users/your_username/path/to/csv/files

The csv files are stored in a map called Data which is in my databricks workspace

The message is clearly telling you that the path you have provided cannot be found. You need to check its exact location, and maybe use the full absolute path, rather than just the relative part.
